# NodeJs authentication in C#

Tags: c#, node.js, authentication

Ive spent quite a bit of time now trying access a api from C# and gotten to the point that my parameters seems to get through but the api is saying signature mismatch. So given the example code below in NodeJs, how should I be creating the signature in C#?

```
var nonce=Math.round(new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds()).getTime()/1000);

var key='Your api key';
var secret='Your api secret';
var client_id='Your client id';
var path='/ac_balance';     //    /ac_balance   /my_pending_orders    /cancel_order
var signature_data=nonce+key+client_id;
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret);     // crypto is a module to encrypt data
      hmac.write(signature_data);
      hmac.end();
var signature = new Buffer(hmac.read()).toString('base64');


//  if path='/ac_balance'
request.post({url:'https://api.somewebsite.com'+path, form: {key:key,nonce:nonce,signature:signature}}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ });
```

This is the code I use to create the signature with in C#:

```
            var data = nounce + key + clientId;
            var signature = CreateToken(data, secret);
...

        private string CreateToken(string message, string secret)
        {
            secret = secret ?? "";
            var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
            byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
            using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
            {
                byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us your current C# code as well? Does the javascript/node code work?

Comment: Ive updated with some of my code. I am told that this node code works by the service provider.

Comment: Note, Ive tried with both ascii and utf8 encoding

Comment: I have a feeling it is to do with the "form:" way of sending the parameters but maybe not since when skipping the key the api complains there is no key..